# Derivative at a point

Tags: symbols

When you write the differential at a point, you write f`(x)|_(x = k). What is the correct LaTeX command for the "|" symbol? Is it just a pipe, or is there a separate mathematical symbol for it?

My LaTeX for the above is:

```
\[f^\prime(x)|_{x = 1} = 5\]
```

Is this formally correct?

Comment: Why not simply `f'(1)=5`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not a differential, but a derivative; they are different things. Since *f'* denotes the derivative of *f*, which is a function of its own, the best notation for the value at 1 is

> *f'*(1)

If you want to use the heavier notation

> *f'*(x)|<sub>*x*=1</sub>

then

```
$f'(x)|_{x=1}$
```

is perfectly good. You may want to define a command for this:

```
\newcommand{\at}[2][]{#1|_{#2}}
```

to be used as

```
$f'(x)\at{x=1}$
```

or, if you need a larger bar to cover a larger function symbol,

```
$f'(x)\at[\big]{x=1}$
```

The optional argument can be one of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`. I wouldn't use an automatically growing bar, because it may give bad results.

Comment: Shouldn't it read `\newcommand*{\at}[2][]{#1|_{#2}}
`?

Comment: @cgnieder Of course!

Comment: It has to be noted that you can understand the Jacobian as a differential and denote it by `f'` as well. Although you are right that in the real one-dimensional case one usually does not use the word differential.

Comment: @canaaerus And why not using `$f'(P)$` (P denoting the point where the Jacobian or Fréchet derivative is computed) as well? Of course it depends on local traditions what notation to use.

Comment: Thanks... and isn't \prime more appropriate than `?

Comment: @egreg: I did not dispute that point. (Although I would there just write `df((P)` or `df_P`)

Comment: @asymptotically Writing `f'` and `f^\prime` in math mode is equivalent and the former is much better both for typing and for reading the source. The second derivative can be written `f''` instead of `f^{\prime\prime}` and here it's easy to see which one is better.

Comment: @asymptotically: But don't use the backtick symbol ` for this cause.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that cleared it up.
@canaaerus Oops, I meant to type "'", not "`"

Answer (score 8):

Basically just using `|` is mostly ok, but I have defined a special purpose command for this, that automatically scales the line vertically:

```
\newcommand\at[2]{\left.#1\right|_{#2}}
```

So you can write `\at{f'}{x=1}`. Alternatively there is also a `\vert` command, which is probably a bit more semantic, but is actually just a synonym for `|`.

Of course this makes sense mostly for bigger expressions like

```
\at{\frac{df}{dt}}{t=1}
```

Concerning the spacing see egregs comment, although I didn't notice this before.

Comment: I tried both, and they produced the same output as "|", except that the \at command had an extra pixel to the left. And the \rvert command was undefined, but \vert produced the same as "|". Is the "|" semantically correct or should I use something different?

Comment: You're introducing unwanted spacings at the left (1.2pt, which is quite noticeable): probably `{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace#1\right|_{#2}}` (with an additional pair of braces) is better. Also `\right|` and `\right\rvert` are equivalent; I wouldn't use `\rvert` in the `\left`-`\right` free version, but `|` which is an ordinary symbol, while `\rvert` is a "closing atom".